# prevent test/reset plug from tripping when electrical current stops?

Tags: electricity

I am installing an electric garage heater. The heater has a 120v wall plug with a test and reset buttons. I am plugging the heater into an outlet that is on a timer switch. Everything works as expected, however when the timer commences the wall plug trips and I have to press the reset button to get the heater to work again.

Is there any way to prevent the plug from tripping when electrical current stops?

Could I replace the test and reset plug with a regular plug?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please keep in mind that questions about the use of electronic appliances are off-topic. Your question is strongly related to the use of electronics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/119374/113182

In short, the GFCI plug is going to trip when power is stopped by the timer. The resolution is to install the GFCI upstream from the timer, replace the heater GFCI plug with a regular plug, and then add a warning sticker on the modified heater plug "FOR USE IN GFCI PROTECTED OUTLETS ONLY".

Answer (score 1):

Does your heater or your timer have a ground fault? You can test for that. The test/reset plug is called a Ground Fault Current Interrupter, or GFCI. The GFCI works by monitoring current flow in the load and trips if it sees an imbalance. The ‘imbalance’ is assumed to be current flowing to ground instead of the return line.

Test 1 - heater by itself. Plug it in to the GFCI and try turning it on and off.

Test 2 - timer. Try the timer with a known load - use a lamp or even better, a high-watt load like a toaster, electric kettle, etc.

Test 3 - known load by itself. Use that high-watt load from test 2.

If all 3 fail, chances are the GFCI itself is faulty. They’re inexpensive and easy to replace. If only 1 or 2 fail, suspect the heater or timer, respectively.

I would not recommend replacing the GFCI with an ordinary receptacle. A garage is a ‘wet’ location - like outdoor - so the GFCI is providing an extra measure of safety.

In 120V countries, a newer type of protection is available: the Arc Fault Current Interrupter (AFCI), which detects abnormal spikes in current characteristic of arcing. This is available as a breaker, or as a dual-mode GFCI/AFCI receptacle. Something to consider if you’re replacing the receptacle (and a very good idea for a garage plug.)

Comment: AFCI is mainly useful for protecting wires in walls. An AFCI recep is fairly silly unless  you have a rats nest plugged into it.